# Perform aggregate operations on varbinary datatype sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to perform aggregate functions on varbinary column in sql server. Snippet below gives me error that datatype varbinary(max) is invalid.

```
  DECLARE @vbtest TABLE(  
  al varbinary(MAX)  
  )
  insert into @vbtest values(0x0000000000000004)
  insert into @vbtest values(0x0000000000000006)
  insert into @vbtest values(0x0000000000000008)
  select sum(al) from @vbtest
```

is there any way to perform aggregate operations on varbinary datatype.

Note : I can not convert to int/Bigint because my varbinary value is bigger than bigint datatype.

Comment: may be cast to bigint can help for you: select sum(CAST(al AS BIGINT)) from @vbtest

Comment: actually my value can be greater that the limits of bigint 2^63-1. That's what I have written in note.

Comment: Looks like it will be difficult to do in SQL.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? How would you sum binary data?

Comment: I will be storing bigintegers in binary format

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a CLR aggregate UDF. Here are some examples:

[Create CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=vs.90).aspx)

[SQL CLR Binary CLR Aggregate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2421d9bf-704e-4a97-b764-de4d56d15358/sql-clr-binary-clr-aggregate-can-it-be-done-more-efficiently?forum=sqlnetfx)

Here's an example I wrote involving Bitwise OR operations:

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
    IsInvariantToNulls = true,
    IsInvariantToOrder = true,
    IsNullIfEmpty = true,
    MaxByteSize = -1, // -1 represents values above 8000 bytes up to 2 GB.
    Name = "udfClrAggVarbinaryBitwiseOR")]
public struct udfClrAggVarbinaryBitwiseOR : IBinarySerialize
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Deserialize from the reader to recreate the struct
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "r">BinaryReader</param>
    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        this.Bytes = r.ReadBytes((int)r.BaseStream.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Serialize the struct.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "w">BinaryWriter</param>
    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.Bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to compute bitwise operations.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to inform if the accumulation has received values
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        this.Bytes = new byte[4]; // this was just arbitrarily set for starting values.
        this.HasValue = false;
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlBinary Value)
    {
        if (Value.IsNull)
        {
            // do nothing.
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = (byte[]) Value;
            if (!HasValue)
            {
                // if this is the first value received, take it.
                this.Bytes = bytes;
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise, compute the bitwise OR operation.
                this.Bytes = bytes.Bin_Or(this.Bytes); // The Bin_Or extension method was defined in the link below.

            }
            this.HasValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Merge(udfClrAggVarbinaryBitwiseOR Group)
    {
        if (Group.HasValue)
        {
            this.Bytes = Group.Bytes.Bin_Or(this.Bytes);
        }
    }

    public SqlBinary Terminate()
    {
        // Put your code here
        //if (HasValue)
        //{
            return this.Bytes;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    return System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
        //}
    }
}
```

I used the code from here for the Bin_Or: [Binary operations on byte arrays, with parallelism and pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328740/Binary-operations-on-byte-arrays-with-parallelism)

The SqlUserDefinedAggregate attribute must be set to Format.UserDefined (i.e. not the default Format.Native) when implementing custom serialization, and serialization must be setup manually by implementing IBinarySerialize. I provide an example below.

Deploying CLR functions can be a pain unless you correctly setup database deployment directly from your Visual Studio database project. (You will need the SQL Data Tools installed first.) The key is to correctly setup your database settings in your Visual Studio database project under project settings -> Database Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Set Trustworthy = true.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014. (I also needed to set my .NET version in the project properties -> SQLCLR -> Target framework to 4.5.2 to get it to deploy from VS 2015 to SQL Server 2014.)

Then, to setup publishing, right click your database project and select Publish Database. In Advanced Publish Settings, check "Always re-create database." (Be sure you backup your database before you deploy!!!) For this to work, you will need a SQL script that contains your data and include it as part of your deployment.

To generate the script, in SQL Server Management Studio, right click your database and go to Tasks -> Generate Scripts... -> (Script entire database) -> Next -> Advanced -> General -> Types of data to script = Data Only. Then save to a new sql script file.
Then add this existing file to your Visual Studio database project, and in the script properties in Visual Studio, set the Build Action to PostDeploy. This ensures the data is loaded after your database is re-created during the publishing process.

To debug, you must enable debugging and ensure that your firewall is adequately opened up. To debug, you will also need to run VS as administrator and right-click your server instance in the Visual Studio SQL Server object explorer and select "Allow SQL/CLR Debugging." This needs to be done every time VS is started. (It's somewhat annoying, but I haven't found a better way.)

In my provided example, I also needed to set the permission level to UNSAFE in the SQLCLR project settings, and I needed to add the class for the Bin_op functions in a separate C# project; then, I compiled that project (also as .NET 4.5.2), added that project as a reference to my database project, and marked the assembly reference property Permission Set = Unsafe.

Comment: Frankly, I forgot the requirement also. Thanks for the response. I will try to go through it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I forgot the requirement also"?

Comment: I had asked this question long back, a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING()`. Quick example:

```
-- get the actual data
DECLARE @tmp varbinary(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 bTemplate
FROM TB_USER_TEMPLATE ORDER BY nUserIdn, nIndex, nFingerIndex)
DECLARE @sum int = (SELECT TOP 1 nTemplatecs
FROM TB_USER_TEMPLATE ORDER BY nUserIdn, nIndex, nFingerIndex)

-- begin calc using 
DECLARE @i int = 0, @calc int = 0
WHILE @i < LEN(@tmp)
BEGIN
    SET @calc += CAST(SUBSTRING(@tmp, @i + 1, 1) AS int)
    SET @i += 1
END

SELECT @sum, @calc -- should be equal
```